# Column name having @ symbol

Tags: c#, mysql, special-characters

I am executing a dynamically generated MySQL query using C# code. An exception gets thrown:

```
CREATE TABLE dump ("@employee_OID" VARCHAR(50));
```

> "{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\"@employee_OID\" VARCHAR(50))' at line 1"}"

I cannot skip the '**@**' symbol from the Column Name.

Manually, using MySQL Workbench, I can get it executed after executing the following query.

```
SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
```

Following is the code I am able to produce:

```
MySqlConnection conn = null;
MySqlCommand cmd = null;
string mySQLConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySQLAutomationServerConnectionString"];
//Dynamically getting generated using some other code
string sqlQueryString = "CREATE TABLE dump ("@employee_OID" VARCHAR(50));";

try
{
    conn = new MySqlConnection(mySQLConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQueryString, conn);
    executionResultStatus = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MySQL Exception: " + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

I have tried to execute the "SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';" query before this gets executed using the code right before executing this code, its not working. What shall I do?

Comment: How did you try setting sql_mode? Can you show the exact code you tried.

Comment: you don't need to add quotes around the `@employee_OID`

Comment: `SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';` is dangerous because you disable all other sql modes for that session on the server. Atleast use `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ANSI_QUOTES')`

Answer (score 1):

Change your command to

```
string sqlQueryString = "CREATE TABLE dump (`@employee_OID` VARCHAR(50));";
```

Notice how there are two backticks before and after the problematic name (ALT+096)
This will allow your engine to ignore the character @ used to identify parameters

Comment: Thanks mate. You made it so easy.